# Understanding Flutter Dependency and Build.gradle relationship

Tags: android, flutter, dependencies, build.gradle

I'm following [this guide](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) on adding Firebase Messaging to my simple Flutter app. Within the guide it states to add the following dependency to *[app-name]/android/app/build.gradle*:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:<latest_version>'
```

It all works fine.  But i'm wondering why must one do this when the required flutter plugin "firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3", which is already added as a dependency within the flutter pubspec.yaml file, has already stated within its own build.gradle file the following:

```
implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:${getRootProjectExtOrCoreProperty("FirebaseSDKVersion", firebaseCoreProject)}")
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
```

I, of course removed the line within *[app-name]/android/app/build.gradle* to see what would happen and got the following error message:

```
*Application.java:14: error: cannot access FirebaseMessagingService
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
                                       ^
class file for com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService not found*
```

So is the rationale then whatever is a dependency stated within a Flutter plugin means it is only scoped within the flutter application it is attached to (everything within the LIB folder)?  And if i make any changes outside this area (ie.  within the root Android folder then i must deal with build.gradle and such?

Comment: From this case, flutter need native code to run background service. this [Method Channel](https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/plugin/common/MethodChannel.html) class is used by flutter to communicate with native code. It mean Flutter must add dependency on native code likes `build.gradle` Android and `Podfile` iOS. I am sorry for my bad english.